# Record video and upload it to server in ipad2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to write a code to start recording a video and upload it to a server using ipad2. I have tried using AVCaptuire session but it is giving me error:

> NSOSStatusErrorDomaincode=12780

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to record video using AVCaptureSession, when you can record it though default UIImagePickerController? It allows you to capture a video. After capturing video you can upload it to server. If you want to stream video to server then you need to use you can refer this link

[Direct Video Capture](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera)